# Javascript/Node - Destructuring array like oject

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecma

It seems duplicated question, but I could not find ideal way to solve it.
(I searched on google about the keyword like 'convert array of object'...
Yes! I'm stupid...)

My current data is like this.

```
[ { name: 'apple', value: 'red' },
  { name: 'banana', value: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'ocean', value: 'blue'}
]
```

And, I want to change it to object like this.

```
[ { 'apple' : 'red' }, { 'banana' : 'yellow' }, { 'ocean' : 'blue' } ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to use `Object.values` and `Object.fromEntries`

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map`: `data.map(el => ({[el.name]: el.value}))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
data.map(el => ({[el.name]: el.value}))
```

Example:

```js
console.log([
  { name: 'apple', value: 'red' },
  { name: 'banana', value: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'ocean', value: 'blue'}
].map(el => ({[el.name]: el.value})));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, el) => {
    acc[el.name] = el.value;
    return acc;
  },
  {}));
```

#### Usage

```
const data = [
  { name: 'apple', value: 'red' },
  { name: 'banana', value: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'ocean', value: 'blue'}
];

const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, el) => {
    acc[el.name] = el.value;
    return acc;
  },
  {}));

console.log(result);
```

**Output:**

`Object { apple: "red", banana: "yellow", ocean: "blue" }`